# Why is R adding empty factors to my data?

Tags: r, statistics, factors

I have a simple data set in R -- 2 conditions called "COND", and within those conditions adults chose between one of 2 pictures, we call house or car. This variable is called "SAW"

I have 69 people, and 69 rows of data

FOR SOME Reason -- R is adding an empty factor to both, How do I get rid of it?

When I type table to see how many are in each-- this is the output

> table(MazeData$SAW)

```
    car house 
2     9    59
```

> table(MazeData$COND)

```
         Apples No_Apples 
    2        35        33
```

> 

Where the heck are these 2 mystery rows coming from? it wont let me make my simple box plots and bar plots or run t.test because of this error - can someone help? thanks!!

Comment: We can't tell without seeing your data.  You probably have two accidentally empty rows in your data set. Can we have a [mcve], or at least the results of `unique(MazeData$SAW)`, `unique(MazeData$COND)`, `str(MazeData)` ?  (Better to include this information by editing your question rather than by responding in a comment ...)

Comment: How can we reproduce your problem without you providing a small snippet of your data?

Comment: You state that you have 69 rows and 69 people. However the total of observations that you have, according to the information you provided, is 68 in both tables, so as @BenBolker said you must have some empty data that is causing R to behave like that...

Comment: unique(MazeData$SAW) HELPED Me so much thanks!! Found it :))